# Is using an empty static method in a class that has a static initializer acceptable/idiomatic?

Tags: java, static, initialization, idioms

I came across the following:

```
class Foo {

  static {
    // setup for logging and configuration
  }

  public static void setup() {
    // do nothing
  }

}
```

Is this idiomatic Java code? Are there specific reasons this should be avoided?

This was found in a test suite.

My initial concern was that initialization could theoretically happen without calling #setup().

Comment: Well, for one, it prevents subclasses of `Foo` from having their own implementation of `setup()`... Would be interested to see what gurus say.

Comment: @mazaneicha There's no problem with a `Bar extends Foo { public static void setup(){...} }`

Comment: @mazaneicha no it doesn't

Comment: I meant "prevents subclasses from overriding `setup()`". Yes hiding it will not be a problem.

Comment: if `setup` method does nothing then it makes no sense of it's existence

Comment: @mazaneicha There is no such thing as "overriding a static method" in Java. This applies to "true" methods, but a static method isn't associated with an instance of a class, so the concept doesn't apply here. And you cannot "hide it" (if I read you correctly).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this idiomatic Java code?

No.

> Are there specific reasons this should be avoided?

Yes: it's confusing, as evidenced by the comments to this question.

> My initial concern was that initialization could theoretically happen
>   without calling #setup().

I would guess the author's concern was that initialization might *not* happen without calling `setup()`. The `setup()` method guarantees that the static initializer has executed its "setup for logging and configuration". Presumably, there are side effects to this configuration which the author seeks to ensure by calling the empty method.

Answer (score 0):

Was the code you posted precisely what you'd come across? In JUnit, it is common practice to use a static method annotated with [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) to configure the test class, and an instance method annotated with [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) to configure each unit test.

(Here are examples of their use: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-before-and-beforeclass-example/)

Otherwise, it does seem odd...

Comment: See the OP's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929588/is-using-an-empty-static-method-in-a-class-that-has-a-static-initializer-accepta/32107117?noredirect=1#comment46115409_28929792) indicating the purpose of the `setup()` method is not part of JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

It's definately not idiomatic as you are restricting those static methods and blocks from inheriting to sub-classes. And yeah,for the Initialization purpose static methods won't need to be called as they are initialized at time of class loading into JVM. And while executing, static blocks are first to execute from top-bottom.